# Stop node/express from (re)serializing nested json data from a sql-server query

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express

how can i tell my node/express endpoint not to serialize a json column comming from a sql-server?

In sql management studio i get this results:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 123454 | {"id":"1","amount":"2","year":"2023"} |

UPDATE:
The result doesnt come directly from a table, its a query with json path!

```
SELECT Column A,
       (SELECT id, anmount, year ... FOR JSON PATH ...) AS Column B
FROM Table 1
```

im making the same query inside my node app ..

```
async function getViewResults(view: String) {
    await pool.connect();
    let result = await pool.request().query(`SELECT .... FROM .... `);
    return result.recordset;
}
```

...  give this to my endpoint ..

```
const aisView = express.Router();
aisView.get("/:view", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const result = await getViewResults(req.params.view);
  res.json(result);
  //res.send(result) //has the same effect
});
```

... and this ist the result. The json data in Column B is treated like text. :-(

```
[{"Column 1":"123454","Column B":"{\"id\":\"1\",\"amount\":\"2\",\"year\":\"2023"}"]
```

On sql server side i tried a lot with json path, json auto json_query etc.
But i think the sql server is not the problem because the Column B in sql management studio doesnt have the extra quotes.

for the moment i added this to my node app, but i am note very happy with this approach.

```
const parsedResults = result.recordset.map((item) => ({
      ColumnA: item.ColumnA,
      ColumnB: JSON.parse(item.ColumnB),
    }));
```

can anyone help me?

thanks

Comment: Don't call `res.json`? That's [_intended_](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json) to stringify what's passed to it.

Comment: i tried to call res.send but getting the same result.

Comment: You sure? _"When the parameter is a `String`, [`res.send`] sets the `Content-Type` to “text/html”"_.

Comment: yes, a console.log inside the function that does the sql-query already has the additional quotes.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a built-in JSON type so whatever library you're using to fetch data from the database is treating it like a string, so you have to manually parse it in the code. If you're using Sequelize you can create a getter function for the column which will do it automatically.

Comment: you are right ... i oversimplified the code, sorry. The Column B comes from a subquery with for json path.
But in the SQL Management Studio the result is without quotes?!